# Back Button Intent On Title bar of Fragment Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments

How to **intent** from `Fragment Activity Class` going to a `Fragment Class`?

the code below that i posted was used in an **activity class** where in there is a `back button on the title bar.`

now what i want to do is the same but i want to `implement it in an fragment class`

I tried this in my Activity Class..

```
   ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and also

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    finish();
    return true;

}
```

Comment: can u explain clearly. while clicking the home button you need to pass an intent ah?

Comment: Yep i want to intent to the previous fragment.

Comment: @AndroidNewbie then you should have added the framgent to the backstack so that you can pop the same accordingly

Comment: yes as Raghunandan said, you should add the fragment in backstack and call backpress in the home button click or u can switch the fragment if u dont want to add to that to the backstack

Comment: @AndroidNewbie first fragment is hosted by a activity. so from activity if you need to got a fragment then you need to navigate to the activity that hosts that fragment

Comment: @Raghunandan so it means that i cant directly go to a fragment that i want?

Comment: @AndroidNewbie yes you can. activity is the one that hosts the fragment. so navigate to activity there you can add fragment to the container. But i am confused because your question is not very clear.

Comment: the code above that i posted was used in an activity class where in there is a back button on the title bar.
now what i want to do is the same but i want to implement it in an fragment class

Comment: @Raghunandan i edited the statement above.

Comment: @AndroidNewbie use `getActivity().getActionBar()` in fragment

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {

        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch(id)
        {

        case android.R.id.home:
            // if (page == PAGE_CHILD) finish();
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        finish();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

For fragments u can use

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.popBackStack();
```

at the place of Intent.

Or replace the fragments

```
        LoginScreen firstFragment = new LoginScreen();

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.article_fragment, firstFragment).commit();
```

Comment: what is the purpose of android.R.id.home
?

Comment: @AndroidNewbie see changes to my answer